# Position dynamic divs over an HTML table

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a event calender using HTML table and jQuery. I have made my calender using **HTML table**. I now want to show events in that table.

My idea was to create divs dynamically using jQuery and position those divs right above a particular table cell.

I cannot append a div to a particular table cell since some events can span multiple days (therefore multiple cells).

So I wanted to set the position of my dynamically created divs to absolute, and give it a higher z-index, so that it floats above the HTML table.

But now I cannot find out how to calculate the position of a particular table cell. Using jQuery I can calculate the row index and column index, but I want the x and y position.

Comment: Some code or demo, else than talks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two jquery inbuilt function to do so

> [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)
>
> [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

### Usage

```
 //Where   p is the first paragraph of the page
```

**Offset**

```
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
```

**Position**

```
var p = $( "p:first" );
var position = p.position();
$( "p:last" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

**For TD offset**

take a loot at this

**[Example Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfGBh/)**

Comment: My calender more like a routine roster, it is not based on months or weeks. So I would have to heavilly modify fullcalender which is not possible

Comment: td element does not have these attributes @Meenesh

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a jquery plugin instead of rewriting again?

http://fullcalendar.io/

you can also check how this plugin overlaps dates table and events table one over another.